# golang mux HandleFunc always 404

Tags: http, go

I try to handle HTTP request using mux instead of standart HandleFunc from net/http, because of reasons. With http it used to work, with mux it doesnt.

```
import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)


func init() {

    mx := mux.NewRouter()

    //create a poll
    mx.HandleFunc("/poll", pollCreate)
    mx.HandleFunc("/poll/{id}", loadPoll)
    mx.HandleFunc("/poll/vote", castVote)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mx)
}
```

The following POST request

```
localhost:8080/poll
```

Results in:

```
INFO     2015-06-02 16:23:12,219 module.py:718] default: "POST /poll HTTP/1.1" 404 19
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a simple program (http://play.golang.org/p/9QQEkVED8i). Do you have a minimal, complete, verifiable test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `module.py` suggests that you already have a python program listening to that port and your Go app failed to bind to the port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution.

Change

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mx)
```

To

```
http.Handle("/", mx)
```

Comment: This needs more of an explanation. You no longer specify the port to listen on, so... what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the default handler. It's always better to keep the method along with the handlers.

```
 import (
        _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        _ "io/ioutil"
        "net/http"
    )


func init() {

    mx := mux.NewRouter()

    //create a poll
    mx.Path("/").HandlerFunc(indexHandler)
    mx.PathPrefix("/poll", pollCreate).Method("POST)
    mx.PathPrefix("/poll/{id}", loadPoll)
    mx.PathPrefix("/poll/vote", castVote)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mx)
}
```